# Installed a python package from Alpine Repository, but not available in python

Tags: python-2.7, docker, alpine-linux

I've built a docker image with Alpine linux.

In my Dockerfile, is the following line

```
RUN apk add --update py-numpy py-numpy-dev  py-scipy  py-numpy-f2py --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community
```

I see some log messages along the lines of

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/3) Installing py-numpy (1.14.3-r1)
(2/3) Installing openblas (0.3.0-r0)
(3/3) Installing py2-numpy (1.14.3-r1)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r1.trigger
OK: 389 MiB in 104 packages
```

but when I run the docker image, and drop into python and run

import numpy as np

I get an

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Full Terminal session here

```
/app # python
Python 2.7.15 (default, Sep 12 2018, 02:38:23) 
[GCC 6.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>>
```

so I'm a little stumped as to why the apk packages are not getting picked up?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Tyler

Full Dockerfile.

Note: I was also struggling with Pandas and scipy so was looking at other docker files on the web, and i'm sure this can be cleaned up a bit.

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine3.8

RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
  && apk add ca-certificates \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual=build_dependencies make cmake gcc g++ git linux-headers libstdc++ && \
    apk del build_dependencies  && \
    apk add --no-cache libstdc++  && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

#RUN apk add --update python-dev python py-pip py-setuptools
RUN apk add --no-cache --update musl musl-dev zlib libxml2 libxml2-dev libxml2-utils libxslt libxslt-dev py-httplib2 && \
    apk add --no-cache --update musl libffi libffi-dev libressl-dev gfortran libgfortran libstdc++ libgcc  cython cython-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache --update py-lxml py-jinja2 py-cffi py-cryptography py-netifaces py-mock py-markdown py-requests py-requests-oauthlib py-click && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*


#from the Community alpine repo
RUN apk add --no-cache --update py-numpy py-numpy-dev  py-scipy  py-numpy-f2py --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ARG PANDAS_VERSION=0.23.4
RUN apk add --no-cache python-dev py-pip libstdc++ && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ && \
    ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h && \
    pip install pandas==${PANDAS_VERSION} && \
    apk del .build-deps


WORKDIR /app
ONBUILD ADD . /app

# Clean up APT when done
RUN  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*

CMD ["/bin/ash"]
```

Comment: For me it is working fine; can you post the whole Dockerfile?

Comment: @valiano  Thanks for comment;  I have edited the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the Dockerfile @mcmasty, but even with it, I can't reproduce the problem. Perhaps you did some other steps in that container after running it? FWIW, I'm running `Docker version 17.03.2-ce, build f5ec1e2` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: BTW, few notes: - The apt paths in "Clean up APT when done" part are redundant (no apt in Alpine). - g++ is downloaded and installed twice (since in the beginning it's deleted with `apk del build_dependencies`); that's ashame because it's a big package. - I think it's not necessary to `rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*` in each step - although it saves some space in the layers (which is negligible), the package data is downloaded over and over. - `musl` package is always installed by default.

Comment: Hi @mcmasty, i'm running into the same issue. Have you been able to solve this since?

Comment: @T.Altena  

This was for a side project that I had to put down, and I haven't gotten back to it.  So I don't recall where exactly I left it.  I do recall, I was having some weird PYTHONPATH issue, where I had to manually set the PYTHONPATH.    I don't recall exactly if that helped, but try including the installed package directories explicitly in the  PYTHONPATH.

Sorry I am not able to more helpful.

Cheers,